# changing the default sort in odoo tree view

Tags: python, xml, sorting, odoo, odoo-10

I added this code to the project_issue module. I created a list of priorities and I want the list of my records to be sorted not alphabetically but with the importance of the priority. So this is my code:

```
sort = fields.Text(compute='_compute_sort')
ipriority = fields.Selection([('none', 'None'), 
                             ('low', 'Low'), 
                             ('normal', 'Normal'), 
                             ('medium', 'Medium'),
                             ('high', 'High'),
                             ('urgent', 'Urgent'),
                             ('immediate', 'Immediate')
                             ], string='Issue Priority', required=True, default='none')
@api.one
def _compute_sort(self):
    if self.ipriority == 'none':
        self.sort = 'ggggggg'
    elif self.ipriority == 'low':
        self.sort = 'fffffff'
    elif self.ipriority == 'normal':
        self.sort = 'eeeeeee'
    elif self.ipriority == 'medium':
        self.sort = 'ddddddd'
    elif self.ipriority == 'high':
        self.sort = 'ccccccc'
    elif self.ipriority == 'urgent':
        self.sort = 'bbbbbbb'
    elif self.ipriority == 'immediate':
        self.sort = 'aaaaaaa'
    return self.ipriority
```

Now I want my records to be sorted with the sort variable so I added this code to the tree:

```
    <tree string="Issue Tracker Tree" decoration-bf="message_needaction==True" default_order="name">
        <field name="sort" invisible="1"/>
    </tree>
```

But it doesn't work. The list is not sorted. The sort field has shown in the tree view but I can't click it to sort manually my records.

I edited the first line but adding `store="true"`. But when I test it, sort field is empty. the `_compute_sort` method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I changed the sort field into a selection field:

```
sort = fields.Selection([('a','a'),
                         ('b','b'),
                         ('c','c'),
                         ('d','d'),
                         ('e','e'),
                         ('f','f'),
                         ('g','g'),], string='Sorting', defaut='g')
```

and I changed the method and called onchange api:

```
@api.onchange('ipriority')
def _onchange_sort(self):
    if self.ipriority == 'none':
        self.sort = 'g'
    elif self.ipriority == 'low':
        self.sort = 'f'
    elif self.ipriority == 'normal':
        self.sort = 'e'
    elif self.ipriority == 'medium':
        self.sort = 'd'
    elif self.ipriority == 'high':
        self.sort = 'c'
    elif self.ipriority == 'urgent':
        self.sort = 'b'
    elif self.ipriority == 'immediate':
        self.sort = 'a'
```

And everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner solution would be something like this:

```
sort = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_sort', store=True)
ipriority = fields.Selection([('none', 'None'),
                              ('low', 'Low'),
                              ('normal', 'Normal'),
                              ('medium', 'Medium'),
                              ('high', 'High'),
                              ('urgent', 'Urgent'),
                              ('immediate', 'Immediate')
                             ], string='Issue Priority', required=True, default='none')

@api.multi
@api.depends('ipriority')
def _compute_sort(self):
    sort_order = {
        'immediate': 1,
        'urgent': 2,
        'high': 3,
        'medium': 4,
        'normal': 5,
        'low': 6,
        'none': 7,
    }
    for record in self:
        record.sort = sort_order.get(record.ipriority)
```

This will store your `sort` field so it isn't needing to recompute constantly. It also makes it an `Integer` field rather than `Char` which is easier to read/compare and should work faster.

[Odoo Fields Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#basic-fields)

Comment: Hi, I tried this code and I have two problems: 1- this code `colors="red:sort=='1'"` doesn't work. it works with letters (a instead of 1). 2- I want to hide the sort field from the tree and form view. If I hide it. odoo doesn't compute that field and I have no sort. And this problem occurs in both codes. Yours and mine.

Comment: @Tessnim 1) You don't need the quotes around `1` since it is stored as an integer. `colors="red:sort==1"` should work appropriately. 2) Are you using `invisible` to hide it or some other way?